# transformation of excel cells to xml nodes in c#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, linq-to-xml

I am a newbie in C#. I have doubt regarding the transformation of excel sheet to XML in c#. I am currently in the part where I have some cells, that I have to access and print corresponding XML nodes to them in the XML file that I have created. For eg: If the cell A1 is there, it should print <abc> node. This has to be hardcoded. I want to do this by LINQ to XML, using XElement and XDocument. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/097c29/excel-to-xml-conversation-in-visual-studio/ as a starting pointer.

Comment: i have used interop for the rest of the transformation, can i still use:
XmlElement emp = doc.CreateElement("EmpDetails");